# Visualizacion de datos en un Jlabel

Tags: java, jlabel

Tengo un metodo en el paquete "controlador" la clase se llama variables y ahi se van a realizar todas las operaciones con los datos que son traidos desde la base de datos (MySQL), el problema es que mi operacion la estoy realizando dentro de un while y solo muestra el ultimo dato en el Jlabel y necesito que se muestren los valores de ese metodo cada vez que se realice la operacion

```
public Double Consult() throws SQLException {
    Double area = null;
    if (Buscar()) {
        ResultSet res = null;
        conexion c = new conexion();

        int cont = 3;
        while (cont < 9) {
            String consult = ("select * from variables_p where id_variables = " + cont + "");
            res = c.consultar(consult);
            try {
                while (res.next()) {
                    int metro = res.getInt("metros");
                    Double d0 = res.getDouble("D0");
                    Double d30 = res.getDouble("D30");
                    Double d60 = res.getDouble("D60");
                    Double d90 = res.getDouble("D90");

                    area = (6 * (d0 + (2 * d30) + (2 * d60) + d90)) / d0;
                    System.out.println("PRUEBA DE SUMA " + area + " ");
                    cont = cont + 3;

                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.print("NO SE ESTABLECIO CONEXION CON LA BASE DE DATOS" + ex);
            }

        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EL REGISTRO NO EXISTE");

    }

    return area;
}
```

La visualizacion en el Jlabel si la hace pero muestra solo el ultimo dato.

```
String x = Double.toString(va.Consult());
jLabel3.setText(x);
```

¿Cómo podria dividir esos datos?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Lo que quieres es crear JLabel dinámicos o algo así para crear un JLabel por cada elemento del `while`?

Comment: Cada componente tiene algunos usos, para lo que quieres hacer lo mejor sería usar un JTextArea debido a que en un label tiene sus limitaciones si quieres usar salto de linea no es posible a menos que uses HTML en el Label.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes concatenar los valores obteniendo primeramente el valor en el JLabel y agregando el nuevo valor, de esta forma se mostrarían todos los valores, agregando "\n" para que realice un salto de linea:

```
String x = Double.toString(va.Consult());
jLabel3.setText(jLabel3.getText() + x + "\n");
```